# How to show a toast and turn on bluetooth on clicking a button in a widget?

Tags: android, bluetooth, toast, android-pendingintent

This is my code:

```
public class SimpleWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    String number="";
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    Button b;

    //private static final String MyOnClick = "myOnClickTag";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        //final int count = appWidgetIds.length;

        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;


        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SimpleWidgetProvider.class);
            intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.simple_widget);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.actionButton, pendingIntent);

            //views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, getPendingSelfIntent(context, MyOnClick));
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

            //Toast.makeText(context, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

In my widget there is a button (id:actionButton in the layout), what I want is  when I click on this button,  bluetooth of the device will turn on and app will show a toast. I was working on the toast part for testing at first but unable to do it. How to do this? As you can see I am using pending intents, is it impossible to do what I want? Or there are other ways? Searched the net at first but didn't get the exact solution, so asking for your suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Check out this link: http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/11/turn-on-and-off-bluetooth-in-android.html#.VjtNJ7crKM8

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I want. I know how to turn on bluetooth adding listeners, but I am trying to make a control widget here; I cannot add listeners to the button which is inside the widget @activesince93

Comment: You should visit this Repository. This is an example of **FlashLightWidget**. You will find how to get button `onClick` event. In this example `BroadcastReceiver` has been used. Repository: https://github.com/ChiragSavsani/FlashLightWidget

Comment: @activesince93 big code but useful one. Working on it. Thanks!

Comment: @activesince93 Working perfectly! You should comment this one as answer :)

Comment: Sure. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this repository: [FlashLightWidget](https://github.com/ChiragSavsani/FlashLightWidget)

You will find how to get button `onClick` event.
In this example `BroadcastReceiver` is used.

Answer (score 0):

Widget is simple control unit. It will not be able to do the complete flow.

My suggestion would be you put a pending intent to trigger the service / activity which will do it.

You can show the Toast also from there.

Comment: Can you provide some code or link regarding this please?